# Estimating the second largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, eigenvalues

I am currently dealing with the following problem. I am given a matrix $A$ of order $n \times n$ where $n \leq 20.$

The principal $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix of $A$ is symmetric and contains only $\{0,1\}$ as its entries. The $n'$th row and column contains a scaled row sum of this principal sub-matrix. In particular $A$ is not symmetric but its eigenvalues are real.

I would like to determine whether the second largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ of $A$ is greater than $2.$

Its perfectly ok for me if the procedure says this is not so (while in fact it is) as long as I do not get false positives.

Right now I am simply computing the eigenvalues of $A$ and checking the condition but it takes a lot of time given that $A$ is not symmetric.

Hence my question is

> Are there any better (faster) ways to determine if $\lambda_2 > 2?$

I suppose I could evaluate some determinants of the form $A+\epsilon+2I$ and compare signs, but this approach looks really scary to me.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a lot of time. On my machine, calculating the eigenvalues for 10,000 random matrices of order 20x20 using the numpy SVD takes about 4 seconds. Is that too long for your particular problem?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed too long. I need to do that for an extreme amount of matrices.

Comment: How many matrices do you need?

Comment: @nicoguaro Lets say about $2^{30}$ as a rough estimate.

Comment: Your arithmetic in the above comment is a bit off.  $2^{30}$ is about $1 \times 10^{9}$, so if you could get $\lambda_{2}$ in a billionth of a second you could do this for a billion matrices in about 1 second.  At the slow speed of 4 seconds for 10,000 matrices, your $10^{9}$ matrices would take about $4 \times 10^{5}$ seconds or 120 hours.

Comment: Yes, I misread, I understood $2\times 10^{30}$... my bad.

Comment: Calculating, sorting, and choosing the second-largest eigenvalue for $10^5$ matrices of $20 \times 20$ real numbers takes 14.29 seconds using simple parallelization in *Mathematica* 10.0.0 on my Mac Pro.  Thus your entire task takes less than 40 hours... easy, over a weekend.

Comment: Can you specify what the rest of the matrix is?

Comment: @Jernej: You should add to your question that you want to perform this task for a large number of $20 \times 20$ matrices, and if all of these matrices have some similar structure. That structure might be exploitable.

Comment: @SquaredSum Four seconds seems absurdly long for a 20x20?